# Why prefer PROPERTIES over #+CATEGORY

Tags: org-mode

In the manual http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/gtd_workflow.html under the heading **Category tags** the author says that it is pointed out that PROPERTIES should be preferred over CATEGORY. I am not able to find a link that justifies it.

In the same page there is a link to the authors cut down version of his org file http://members.optusnet.com.au/~charles57/GTD/gtdsample.txt which uses CATEGORY and not PROPERTIES.

Comment: The author points out that it was suggested later on, he never edited his newgtd.org to reflect that change, it was associated with the original post.

Comment: now i get it. thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 7):

`#+CATEGORY` propagates linearly through the org file (which is quite difficult to maintain in an tree-structured outline), whereas a property named CATEGORY will apply to a subtree.

I personally use a `#+CATEGORY` declaration at the beginning of each file (to ensure that all entries in the file have a category to show up in the agenda), and then customize subtrees by means of properties.

The referenced manual has an identical argumentation.